# This compound word when reversed is also a compound word

Tags: word

This is a Closed Compound Word ( A single non hyphenated or non seperated word made of 2 seperate words).

> Made up of 2 words say A and B
>
> When reversed it is also a closed compound word. So both AB and BA are
>   closed compound words.
>
> The word AB results from the word BA
>
> It has 5 consonants.

Words only from a standard Webster or Oxford dictionaries please. No proper nouns or slang words.

It is a simple word so please do not go to computers and check all compound words!

There may be 2 solutions. Second one a little stretched.

Hint

> It fills the blanks in the following
>
> That ________ must have come from a _______.
>
> For the second solution
>
> They make them do a lot of ________ in that ________.

Comment: When you say "reversed", do you mean the whole word is reversed or we exchange the two sub-parts. For example, would the word "doghouse", when reversed, become "housedog" or "esuohgod" ?

Comment: Doghouse will become Housedog. But i dont think housedog is a compound word

Comment: It is such a simple word @Chris Happy. Easy to find if you go to a compound word list. Lot more fun if you do not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a simple 5-consonant possibility...

> When you're having a **sleepover**, you might **oversleep**. Hence one results in the other.

A couple more to match that new template:

> That **gunshot** must have come from a **shotgun**.
>
>  That **houseguest** must have come from a **guesthouse**.

And for that second template, maybe:

> They make them do a lot of **housework** in that **workhouse**?

Other words I could think of that don't *quite* fit:

> An **upstart** could come from a **startup** company, but I think the correct form is start-up.
>
>  There's also **overturn** and **turnover**, but they're too much alike.
>
>  A **birdsong** comes out of a **songbird**,  but it has 6 consonants.
>
>  And a **houseboat** could come out of a **boathouse**, I guess, but it has just 4 consonants. Though you could always cheat a little and pluralize it. ;)

Answer (score 5):

I found three solutions:

> BEATDOWN/DOWNBEAT, OVERHANG/HANGOVER, OVERPASS/PASSOVER.

Comment: @Devousi. One restriction is that the word AB results from the word BA.

Comment: @DEEM I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by "AB results from the word BA." Like, in a sentence? As in, "you can get an AB from a BA" should be a valid thought pattern?

Comment: It is like "AB comes from BA" would be a correct clue too. Like a sentence

Comment: @DEEM What do you mean by "comes from"? That would be a *grammatically correct* sentence for any of these pairs.

Comment: Like Passover comes from Overpass. Not correct of course.

Answer (score 0):

> Writeover /overwrite 
>  
>  Comeover /overcome 
>  
>   night over/overnight

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! The puzzle is asking for real English words that could, say, be found in a dictionary, but yours [don't seem to fit that.](https://www.google.com/search?q=Writeover) Your examples are only valid as *separate* words, not as closed compound words. Why not take the [tour](/tour) for an easy badge?